The tag [can] and [could] should be merged to [can-modal] and [could-modal] respectively
The tag:

can (1 question) merged to can-modal (28 questions)
could (11 questions) merged to could-modal (46 questions)

These four tags have no tag wikis (or tag wiki excerpts), so it is not clear that what do the can tag and the could tag used for exactly. I went through all the questions quickly and don’t think that we need the can tag or could tag.
I want to delete the can tag from this question, but the notice was shown when I clicked the edit button:

Another edit is awaiting approval for this post.

So, I can’t do anything to that question.

Seems reasonable. Any objections?

@Laurel If you look at the bottom of the list of tags sorted by "popular" there's quite a few random word tags that would be worth getting rid of on top of these two. (now, however, young, already, etc. etc.)

@ColleenV Some of them can be made into synonyms (kinda mod-only) but the rest will have to be manually deleted, which can be done by anyone who can edit (try not to flood the homepage). However, I think that tags for function words (if they were consistently applied) could be helpful to keep, since they're almost impossible to search for otherwise.

@Laurel I agree - categorizing posts about "a", "of", "for", "be" et. al. so that you can find relevant answers is really difficult in this system. This is actually a problem that is well-suited to be solved with AI helping with searches (and I DO NOT mean providing summaries to answer the question). I wonder if a general "function-words" tag would be helpful to at least narrow down searches and provide a synonym target.

@ColleenV Basically I mean any word with special properties that is hard to search for (this might not strictly match the formal definition). The tags here (can-modal / could-modal) are good examples, and you mentioned some others. Unfortunately, merging them all into a single bigger tag would again make it hard to find any relevant questions. Some of these tags do have better names than the word itself (e.g., "a" is "indefinite-article") but it's not always easy for me to know what that is given that I had a native speaker's education.

@ColleenV As for AI as a solution for tagging, I actually experimented a little with ChatGPT, but I didn't give it enough time (or maybe talent) to make it give good suggestions. I remember getting extremely generic suggestions like "grammar" and "tense" or just whatever was mentioned in the title (too obvious to be helpful). Maybe you'd have better luck with a different AI, but the question remains of how to actually get the tags on each question without being disruptive.

They have been merged.
The pending edit was also approved.
